# Using automapper.collection in aspnet core & ef core doesn't updated edited records in a collection

Tags: asp.net-core, collections, entity-framework-core, automapper, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using asnet boilerplaite aspnet core and ef core. I've initialized automapper.collection in PreInitialize as follows:

```
Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(
    cfg =>{
        cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
        cfg.CreateMap<OrderDTO, Order>().EqualityComparison((odto, o) => odto.ID == o.ID);
        cfg.CreateMap<OrderItemDTO, OrderItem>().EqualityComparison((odto, o) => odto.ID == o.ID);
    }
);
```

I'm using ObjectMapper.Map(odto, o); to map between the dto and entity, but what I find are new orderitem in the orderitems collection within orders save fine, but any edits to existing entries seem to not update to the db.

The order entity and collection are loaded from the repository using the following:

```
var @item = await _orderRepository.GetAll().Include(x => x.Items).Include(x => x.Items).ThenInclude(x => x.Product).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

here is the Update method:

```
    public override async Task<OrderDto> Update(OrderDto input)
    {
        var ord = await _orderManager.GetA(input.Id);

        ObjectMapper.Map(input, ord);

        CheckErrors(await _orderManager.UpdateA(ord));

        return MapToEntityDto(await _orderManager.GetA(input.Id));
    }
```

The values of input and ord variables are as follows when trying to update the orderitem record:

```
    input   {OrderDto}  
    Code    "1" string
    Id  1   int
    Items   Count = 1   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<OrderItemDto>
    -       [0] {OrderItemDto}  
                Id  1   int
                OrderId 1   int
        +       Product {ProductLoadDto}
                ProductId   4   int
                Quantity    22  double
    MovementDate    {28-Jul-18 2:36:41 AM}  System.DateTime


    ord {[Order 1]} Order
    Code    "1" string
    Id  1   int
    Items   Count = 1   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<OrderItem>
    -       [0] {OrderItem 1}
            Id  1   int
            OrderId 1   int
    +       Product {[Product 4]}   Venues.Products.Product
            ProductId   4   int
            Quantity    1   double
    MovementDate    {28-Jul-18 12:06:41 PM} System.DateTime
```

Is there something I'm missing to get automapper.collection to handle the collection edits automatically ?

Comment: show your Order save method and contents of OrderDto and OrderItemDto.

Comment: I've added those details to the original post. Cheers

Comment: Hi guys, I'm still facing this issue. I can verify the new value is in the entity after it is mapped from the dto, so I'm assuming at this point the automapper.collection package would flagged it as modified.  But no update statement is issued to sql for the order item, how/where do I check the state of the changestate for these child entities? Is there something else I need to do with the mapping from dto for it the acknowledge the entity has changed and hence update it?

Comment: Correction, seems both updates or deleted entries from the collection don't apply to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Entity Framework Core repo?

```
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore/tree/development
```

Comment: Thanks Guo, no I hadn't tried that repo. But I get an error when installing it:

Install-Package : Unable to find package 'AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore'

I'm using 
Install-Package AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore 

to install, is the package under a different name ?

I also tried the following with no luck:
Install-Package AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore

Comment: try Automapper.Collection 4.0.0

Comment: @DLedge did you end up finding answer to this ? Would you mind posting if you got any. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used the extension listed here to resolve the issue:
https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/39452054/asp-net-core-with-ef-core---dto-collection-mapping